# Unsubscribe not working when signout in angular and firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angular7

I'm using angular 7, firebase (*Only for authentication*) and mysql(*For saving other data*). Once user signed-In successfully, a request gets data of user from mysql and saves in localStorage. When I sign-out, its signing-out, but again the request (`this.userService.findByUsername(res.user.uid).subscribe(....)` ) sends and gets back the data and store in the localstorage. I unsubscribe when sign-out. But it doesn't work. (Few other varibles and methods are removed in following codes to make it simpler)

```
export class AuthService {
    private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
    user: Observable<firebase.User>;
    private currentUserSubject: BehaviorSubject<User | null>;
    authState: any = null; 

    constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router, private userService:UserService) {
        this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
        this.subscription.add(this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
        this.authState = auth;

        //getting the user object if he already signed-in
        this.currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') | null);        
        this.currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable();
    }))

    signin(email: string, password: string) {      
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            // --- login with email and password in firebase
            this.firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(
                res => {                                     
                    // --- Once login is successful, get the user object form the backend
                    this.subscription =this.userService.findByUsername(res.user.uid).subscribe(data=>{                               
                        this.currentUserSubject.next(data);                                                 
                        localStorage.setItem("currentUser", JSON.stringify(data));   
                        resolve(this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser); 
                    })
            } ,
                err => {reject(err); }
            ).catch(err => {
                console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
            });
    });

    }

    async logout() {        
        await this.firebaseAuth.auth.signOut().then(()=>{
            this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
            this.currentUserSubject.complete();
            this.subscription.unsubscribe()
            localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');       
            this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're probably calling `signin()` somewhere else after you call `logout()`. I'm assuming `this.userService.findByUsername()` is using `HttpClient`. If so, then it returns a self-closing Observable, no need to unsubscribe. Also, I don't understand what you're trying to do with `new Subscription()`

Comment: @delashum I don't use anywhere else. I unsubscribe because I had a doubt whether its unsubscribed or not. This `signin()` is called, when user presses sign-in button only.

Comment: If that's the case then what I would try is `this.userService.findByUsername(res.user.uid).pipe(first()).subscribe(...)`. this will guarantee that only one response is received.

Comment: @delashum this works, thank you so much, but may I know how this happened? because, Angular automatically closes the subscription and I signed-out also

Comment: Glad to hear it. I created an answer that says the same thing if you wouldn't mind accepting.
Not sure what is causing, would have to see more code to find the problem. It could be anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the `first()` operator as follows to guarantee only one value makes it through subscription.

```
this.userService.findByUsername(res.user.uid).pipe(first()).subscribe(...)
```